# AVD Emulator How can I remove the front camera hole?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I created an android emulator for Pixel 8 and Pixel 8 Pro. I edited the mask images in the Skins folder with Photoshop. It came exactly as I edited it in API 33, that is, it came with the camera hole deleted. However, in API 34, the camera hole comes by default. I also noticed that the status bar height is higher.
My question is; How can I remove the camera hole and reduce the status bar height for API 34?
I changed the images in these folders, but the emulator with the camera hole opened again.

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\resources\device-art-resources\pixel_8_pro

C:\Users\My_PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\pixel_8_pro

Check this images;

[pixel_8_pro folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2PpJ.png)

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXGX0.png)